# $|f(f(z))-z^2|$ must be large somewhere in the disc $\mathbb{D}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I wish to prove the statement shown in the following block. I thought this may have appeared in the Math Stack before; sorry if I failed to find it (see "Research" below).

The proposition seems to call for a proof via H.A. Schwarz Lemma, but I am interested in any proof of it.

> Let $\sup$ always mean the supremum in the unit open disc
> $\mathbb{D}$. Let $f$ map $\mathbb{D}$ into $\mathbb{D}$ analytically, and fix the origin. Prove that $$\sup \left|f(f(z))-z^2\right| \,\,\geq\,\,\frac{1}{4}.$$

**My Attempt.**

If it happens that $f$ is a rotation, $z \mapsto {e^{i\psi}}z,$ then the result follows from the choice $z=1/2 \in $ the disc:

$$\left|f(f(\frac{1}{2}))-(\frac{1}{2})^2\right| \,\,\geq\,\,\left|f(f(\frac{1}{2}))\right|-\left|\frac{1}{4}\right|\,\,=\,\,\left|f(\frac{1}{2})\right|-\frac{1}{4}\,\,=\,\,\left|\frac{1}{2}\right|-\frac{1}{4}\,\,=\,\,\frac{1}{4},$$

since rotation means $|z|\,=\,|f(z)|$ for any $z$ in $\mathbb{D}$.

Therefore we assume $f$ is not a rotation. By Schwarz Lemma, we know $f'(0) \in \mathbb{D}$, and we know $|f(z)|<|z|<1$ throughout the disc.

(*Starting here I pursue an idea; I am not sure if it is helpful...*) Define the function $$\phi(z)\,\,=\,\,\frac{f(f(z))-z^2}{2},$$

and note that it also satisfies the hypotheses of the Schwarz Lemma. It is easy to check that $\phi$ is not a rotation when $f$ is not a rotation. So now our goal is to show

> $$\sup |\phi(z)| \,\,\geq\,\,\frac{1}{8}.$$

**Remarks.**

That's what I have done. The derivative of $\phi$ is $\frac{1}{2}(f'(f(z))f'(z)-2z)$, and using this we can know that $|\phi'(0)|<\frac{1}{2}.$ Of course we know $|\phi(z)|<|z|<1$ throughout the disc.

Another idea is to pass to series expansions of $f$ and $\phi$.

**Research.**

1. [Approach Zero search results.](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3Aschwarz%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24f%5Cleft(f%5Cleft(z%5Cright)%5Cright)-z%5E2%24&p=1)
2. Schwarz Lemma search results: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?page=11&tab=Relevance&q=schwarz%20lemma

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts towards confirming the lack of a duplicate, and +1. I'd love to know where you found this problem(not for the sake of context, but in the hope that there will be great problems there!)

Comment: Sure thing Teresa. This is from a past qualifying exam at a U.S. college. I can try to find the link...

Comment: No need! This is just a magnificent question all round. I hope it will receive a great answer.

Comment: Doubt that this will be of any help at all but the $\frac14$ reminds me of the following theorem: Suppose $f : \Bbb D \to \Bbb C$ is analytic, injective, and satisfies $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$. Then, the image of $f$ contains the open disc $D(0, \frac14)$. (A reference is Theorem 14.14 of Rudin's RCA.)

Comment: Unless I made an error, the lower bound $1/4$ can be replaced by $1/2$. I posted a follow-up question asking for more precise estimates: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4217283/42969.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $f(z)=az+bz^2+..$, by Parseval (integrating $|f|^2$ on $|z|=r<1$ and letting $r \to 1$) we get that $|a|^2+|b|^2+..\le 1$ so $|b| \le 1$

But now $f(f(z))-z^2=a^2z+(ab+a^2b-1)z^2+...$ and if the result would be false, we would get again by Parseval that:

$|a|^4+|ab+a^2b-1|^2 \le 1/16$ so $|a| \le 1/2, |ab+a^2b| \le 3/4$ hence $|ab+a^2b-1|^2 \ge 1/16$ so we must have equality in the inequalities above or $|a|=1/2, |b|=1$ and that contradicts $|a|^2+|b|^2+..\le 1$ so we are done!

Comment: I will need to study some new (for me) material in order to understand your answer; thanks Conrad. I assume you are using this theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem

Comment: How do you get $|ab + a^2b| \le 3/4$? I can see you deducing $|ab + a^2b - 1| \le 1/4$ but that doesn't imply the former inequality.

Comment: Very nice!  – If I understand your proof correctly, $1/4$ is *not* the best possible bound.

Comment: @Martin looks like that

Comment: @Arya we use that $|a| \le 1/2, |b| \le 1$ and the triangle inequality to get that at most $1/2+1/4=3/4$; then $|1-ab-a^2b| \ge 1-3/4=1/4$

Comment: @Conrad: Ah yes, it's clear now.

Comment: One estimates :$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta}|^2d\theta \le 1$ (since $|f| \le 1$) and when you expand $|f(re^{i\theta}|^2=f\bar f$ and switch integral with series (allowed by absolute convergence for $|z|=r<1$) the integrals of the non-diagonal terms are zero by periodicity, so the original integral consists of just the diagonal terms which are constant in $\theta$, namely $|a|^2r^2+|b|^2r^4+...$ and then letting $r \to 1$ we get the estimate; same for $f(f(z))-z^2$ but now we get the integral at most $1/16$ if we assume  $|f(f(z))-z^2| < 1/4$

Answer (score 6):

The following solution is very similar to what Conrad wrote. Instead of [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) we use an estimate which can be obtained from the [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) and its corollary, the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem):

> Let $f(z) = a z + b z^2 + \dots$ be holomorphic in the unit disk $\Bbb D$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(\Bbb D) \subset \Bbb D$. Then $|a|^2 + |b| \le 1$.

*Proof:* If $f$ is a rotation then $|a| = 1$ and $b = 0$ and we are done. Otherwise the function $g(z) = f(z)/z$ maps $\Bbb D$ into itself and the Schwarz-Pick theorem can be applied to $g$:
$$
\frac{|g'(z)|}{1-|g(z)|^2} \le \frac{1}{1-|z|^2} \, .
$$
Setting $z=0$ gives $|g'(0)| \le 1-|g(0)|^2$, which is exactly the desired estimate.

---

Now we can can proceed as follows: Let
$$
 f(z) = az + bz^2 + \dots
$$
be a holomorphic function which maps the unit disk into itself and fixes the origin and assume that
$$
 \sup \{ |f(f(z))-z^2| : z \in \Bbb D \} < \frac 1 4 \, .
$$
Then
$$
 F(z) = 4 \bigl(f(f(z)) - z^2\bigr) = 4 a^2 z + 4 \bigl(a(a+1)b - 1\bigr) z^2 + \dots
$$
also maps the unit disk into itself and fixes the origin. The above lemma gives
$$
 16 |a|^4 + 4 |a(a+1)b - 1| \le 1 \, .
$$
It follows that $|a| \le 1/2$ and
$$
 \frac 14 \ge |a(a+1)b - 1| \ge 1 - |a||a+1||b| \ge 1- \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac 3 2 \cdot 1 = \frac 1 4.
$$
So equality holds everywhere in the above inequality chain. In particular, $|a| = 1/2$ and $|b| = 1$, which is a contradiction to $|a|^2 + |b| \le 1$.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you for diving into this problem with me. It gave me a good reason to study Schwarz-Pick and its proof. There were only two moments when I had to pause and fill in some details. For the sake of fellow asses trying to cross these bridges, I will add comments below. I will follow your follow-up question with interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4217283

Comment: Details on concluding that $|a|=1/2$ and $|b|=1$: by the inequality(equality) chain, we know $0<|a||a+1||b|=3/4.$ Suppose $|a|<1/2$ or $|b|<1$. Then $0<|ab|<1/2.$ Hence $3/2 < |a+1|$. But that cannot be, for $|a+1|\leqslant |a|+1\leqslant 3/2.$

Comment: Details on why the function $g(z) = f(z)/z$ maps $\Bbb D$ into itself: this conclusion appears in the proof of the ordinary Schwarz Lemma. It follows from the Maximum Principle (continuous on a compact version) that $g(z)$ maps $\Bbb D$ into $\overline{\Bbb D}$. But if $\zeta\in\Bbb D$ with $g(\zeta)\in \partial \Bbb D$ then $g$ must be constantly $g(0)=f'(0)\in \partial \Bbb D,$ and $f$ is a rotation, a possibility already ruled out in the proof of the estimate. (Here "$g$ constant" follows from the other form of Maximum Principle, the one dealing with a domain.)

Comment: @311411: The Schwarz lemma already states that – unless $f$ is  a rotation – $|f(z)| < |z|$ for $z \ne 0$, and $|f'(z)| < 1$. That implies $|g(z)| < 1$ for all $z$.

Comment: Aha, quite right. No need to prove Schwarz Lemma again; we just apply (the "furthermore" part of) it to $f$.