# How large must $f(f(z))-z^2$ be in the unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

This is a follow-up question to [$|f(f(z))-z^2|$ must be large somewhere in the disc $\mathbb{D}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200217/ffz-z2-must-be-large-somewhere-in-the-disc-mathbbd), where the following was proven:

> Let $f$ be holomorphic in the unit disk $\Bbb D$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $|f(z)| < 1$ for all $z \in \Bbb D$. Then
> $$ \tag{*}\sup_{z \in \Bbb D} |f(f(z))-z^2| \geq \frac 14 \, .$$

The given proofs work by assuming the contrary, and applying Parseval's identity or the Schwarz-Pick theorem to $F(z) = 4(f(f(z))-z^2)$. This leads to inequalities for the first Taylor coefficients of $f$ which can not be satisfied.

Inspection of those proofs shows that the used inequalities are not sharp, which leads to the conjecture that the number $1/4$ in $(*)$ can be replaced by a larger number.

Therefore I am curious what the best possible lower bound in $(*)$ would be. Let
$$
 {\cal F} = \{ f: \Bbb D \to \Bbb D \text{ holomorphic}, \, f(0) = 0 \}
$$
be the family of functions to which the Schwarz lemma can be applied. For $f \in \cal F$ define
$$
 S(f) = \sup_{z \in \Bbb D} |f(f(z))-z^2| \, ,
$$
and finally set
$$
 C = \inf_{f \in \cal F} S(f) \, .
$$

We know that $C \ge 1/4$, and the question is if better estimates or the exact value can be computed. What I can show is that
$$ \tag{**}
 \boxed{\frac 12 \le C \le 1 \, .}
$$

The upper bound $C \le 1$ comes from choosing $f(z) = 0$. For the lower bound one proceeds as in the linked question above, but with more careful estimates.

Assume that $f \in \cal F$, $f(z) = az + bz^2 + \cdots$, and $$ \sup_{z \in \Bbb D} |f(f(z))-z^2| < 1/2 \, .$$ Then $|a|^2 + b \le 1$ and
\begin{align}
1 &\ge 4 |a|^4 + 2 |a(a+1)b - 1| \\&\ge 4 |a|^4 + 2\left(1 - |a|(|a|+1)(1-|a|^2)\right) \\&= 6|a|^4+2|a|^3-2|a|^2-2|a|+2.\end{align}

On the other hand, plotting the right-hand side as a function of $|a| \in [0, 1]$ shows that it is always strictly larger than one:

[image]

It is also confirmed by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+6*x%5E4%2B2*x%5E3-2*x%5E2-2*x%2B2+over+%5B0%2C1%5D) that the minimum of the right-hand side is $\approx 1.1185 > 1$. This is a contradiction and completes the proof that the supremum is at least $1/2$.

**My question: Are there better bounds for $C$, or can the exact value be computed?**

Comment: Since $C = 1/2$ seems like a natural answer, it should be pointed out that your argument works for $C = 1/1.8189 \approx 0.54978$.

Comment: @mathworker21: Yes, I have a lower bound of $\approx 0.5498$ now. A better method is needed to improve the bounds significantly. My current *guess* is that $C=1$.

Comment: It is certainly not $1$: just consider $f(z)=az+2az^2$ with very small $a>0$. Then $f(f(z))-z^2=a^2z+(2a^2-1)z^2+R$ where $|R|\le 18a^3$, so the difference is at most $1-2a^2+a^2+18a^3=1-a^2+18 a^3<1$ when $a<\frac 1{18}$.

Comment: As an extension to @fedja's comment you can test $f(z)=az(z^k-1)/(z-1)$ for some integer $k>1$ and $|a|\le1/\sqrt k$.

Comment: @fedja: Indeed, that gives an upper bound of $\approx 0.99635$.